# Question about perceived stubborn behavior patterns

Tags: behavior

Is there a relative diagnosis for someone who can't simply adapt to and/or use something that is already established?  This type of personality would also need to have their own idea to validate their selection/alternative for peer acceptance.  It could be either severe (I'm guessing this would be narcissistic personality disorder) or mild.

Is this common or categorized in some way?  And are there ways of dealing with this type of personality/behavior?

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg I agree. Thank you. It was difficult searching previously asked questions for the related topic.  #ConfirmationBias

Answer (score 0):

As noted, this is a duplicate and was asked due to the complexity of wording my search terms in a way that related to what I outlined.

### Confirmation Bias